# Issue with Wordpress Contact Form 7 Plugin - Dynamic Text Extension

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use the Contact Form 7 plugin for contact forms on our site. I am using this on a WP installation with multiple sites. We have employment application forms on each site, and to identify the site when we do a REST call to our webapp, I would like to include the site_id (or blog_id, I'm unclear on which is the right name) so it can be used to reference the WP site in the other app. I installed the Dynamic Text Extension for this particular task, and this is my first attempt, based on the help docs, to add a hidden field with the blog_id:

`[dynamichidden blog_id id:blog_id "CF7_bloginfo value='blog_id'"]`

and end up with this:

`<input name="dynamichidden-927" value="Elite Trade Painting Calgary" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7dtx-dynamictext wpcf7-dynamichidden" id="blog_id" aria-invalid="false" data-hasqtip="true" type="hidden">`

I should note that no matter what I put in the tag, the same value comes up. I know I am editing the right form because if I delete the tag, it disappears completely – but no matter what I change, it always has the wrong value.

https://elitetradepainting.com/calgary/employment-opportunities/

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was looking at the wrong page and thinking that bloginfo() returns the blog id - it doesn't. The DTX developer answered my question in WP forums and advised me to use a shortcode, so I wrote a callback that uses get_current_blog_id:

in functions.php:

```
function get_blog_id_callback() {
  return get_current_blog_id();
}

add_shortcode('get_blog_id', 'get_blog_id_callback');
```

Then the snippet for the control in the Edit Contact Form page is as simple as:

`[dynamichidden blog_id "get_blog_id"]`